# A better way of managing a forms state?

Tags: winforms

I am new to Windows programming, as in my previous work I've mostly been involved with web technologies, and mostly in the backend. I have inherited a Winforms application, and one of my biggest nightmares is navigating through the endless states a form can be in.

To give you an example, a form has the state 'New' and 'Edit' depending on whether the user decided to Add or Edit a record. On this form, we have logic. If this texbox has a certain value, then these other textboxes are disabled, etc. This leads to endless chaining of these rules. So, a textbox's TextChanged event will influence another field. It in turn will fire X event that changes the state of other controls. It quickly devolves into a tangled mess that is impossible to maintain.

There has to be a better way... something simple and elegant that solves this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is to have a single method called `FormatControls()`. In this method, I implement all the logic such as `myTextbox.Enabled = mycheckBox.Checked` and so on.

I call this method from my event handlers in the form, such as on checked changed, etc... I also call it when appropriate (ie, form newly loaded with no data, record loaded from database, etc).  This has suited me well for many years now, it makes everything less complex.

You are correct, if you do not have a pattern in use it can turn into a too-complex thing.

Comment: I like this idea,. I have found though that the FormatControls becomes quite large itself (of course, you can refactor it into smaller bits). I guess the logic has to go somewhere, and it's much better off in one central place than spread out across numerous event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use tha Application.Idle event to perform the enable disable logic and insulate this part from the business logic part.

Comment: This might be considered more "loosely coupled", but risks pinning the CPU at 100%.

Comment: @Reinderien if you don't do costly loop *inside* teh Idle handler, your CPU will not fill any costly load, just because this event is raised by the old Message Loop of windows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Wouldn't the Application.Idle event fire every time the entire application was idle? What if there are many forms in the application? Would I need to figure out which windows are currently showing, and then perform the necessary logic?

Comment: trying it would cost a second, on idle is triggered by the windows message pump when all the messages are processed, and is usually the place where we update the UI status.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what controls you have on your form, you might be able to do away with the separate textboxes and add/delete buttons and replace the whole works with a `DataGrid`.

Comment: I'd have a similar problem with a datagrid. I'd have to disable certain columns based on the values of other cells. This becomes more complex because I'd need to manage this on a row by row basis.